# Doctrine lifecycle callbacks not working with EasyAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony 4 with EasyAdminBundle to create a simple administrative interface. I'm having a few problems trying to automatically set the value for `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns. When creating/updating an entity within EasyAdmin, the configured Doctrine lifecycle callbacks are not called. For example, here's a simple entity that is managed with EasyAdmin, note the lifecycle callback hooks:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // Additional column configuration removed for brevity

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    // Additional getters/setters removed for brevity

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist(): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate(): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

When I create a new product within EasyAdmin, `onPrePersist()` is not called, and when I edit an existing product with EasyAdmin, `onPreUpdate()` is not called.

If I create a new product the "traditional" way, the lifecycle callbacks work exactly as expected. For example:

```
    <?php

    $product = new Product();
    $product->setTitle('Test Product');
    $product->setDescription('Test description');

    // Doctrine lifecycle callbacks work as expected
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($product);
```

Is EasyAdminBundle bypassing Doctrine lifecycle callbacks? If so, why? How do I utilize Doctrine lifecycle callbacks within Doctrine entities managed by EasyAdminBundle?

I understand there is documentation to do something similar with an `AdminController`:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#update-some-properties-for-all-entities

But again, why do I need to do this when we already have Doctrine lifecycle callbacks. My other problem with using an `AdminController` and extending various methods, `persistEntity()` within `AdminController` is never called either.

What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the easy admin bundle, but I couldn't find a reason, why they would break the lifecycle callback system, nor code that says they do. so unless I'm missing something (which might be the case), I'm at a loss. Except possibly ... when you're not working on dev, clearing and warming up the cache might help ... but besides that, I have no ideas.

Comment: Just as a side note - consider using `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` - this provides (amongst many other useful things) the ability for the DB to handle created / updated at properties: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/timestampable.md